# Qt QML component like WPF HwndHost

Tags: wpf, windows, qt, qml, hwnd

We have a desktop windows application that uses a component that needs a `HWND` to be displayed. In a WPF application we use a `HwndHost` to display it. We are trying to make a Qt QML based application to do the same.

Is it possible to host a `HWND` component in a QML application?

It works with a `QQuickWindow`, but the control I attach takes the entire window application area. I would like to bind to a smaller area, like the `rectArea` in the QML below. But a `QQuickItem` does not have a `windId()`, only its parent `window()`. It is possible?
Here is my QML:

```
ApplicationWindow {
  width: 640
  height: 480
  visible: true
  Rectangle {
    objectName: "rectArea"
    id: rectangle1
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "#ffffff"
 }
}
```

And here a cpp snippet:

```
void setHwnd(QQmlApplicationEngine& m_engine) {
  auto root_objects = m_engine.rootObjects();
  m_rootObject = root_objects[0];
  auto rect_area = m_rootObject->findChild<QQuickItem*>("rectArea");
  HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(rect_area->window()->winId());
  // use hWnd here, but it takes the entire window area...
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. Can you tell us how did you eventually solve?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a QWindow (or anything that inherits from it), you can obtain HWND by calling `winId` method. You will need to typecast it like this:

```
QWindow pWindow;
// create pWindow
HWND hWnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(pWindow->winId());
```

Answer (score 0):

A `Rectangle` does not have its own `HWND`. You can only retrieve the `HWND` for the whole window. You have to restrict yourself to the rectangle are, e.g. when hosting a OpenGL application:

```
 glViewport(x(), windowHeight - y() - height(), width(), height());
```